# Apple Push notification Problem gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I almost done my app but suddenly an error appear

The ERROR:

```
    Ld build/urbantest.build/Release-iphoneos/urbantest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/urbantest normal armv7
cd /Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.1
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -L/Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest/Airship -F/Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest/build/urbantest.build/Release-iphoneos/urbantest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/urbantest.LinkFileList -dead_strip -all_load -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib -miphoneos-version-min=4.1 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lUAirship-1.0.4 -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreTelephony -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3 -lz -o /Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest/build/urbantest.build/Release-iphoneos/urbantest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/urbantest

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_UA_ASIDownloadCache in /Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest/Airship/libUAirship-1.0.4.a(UA_ASIDownloadCache.o) and /Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/urbantest/build/urbantest.build/Release-iphoneos/urbantest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/UA_ASIDownloadCache.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1**

Plz help me solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you are trying to use [AirShip](http://urbanairship.com/) library for Push Notification that embed ASIHTTPRequest library. Have you also add by yourself [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for network stuff?

If yes the linker found two symbol with the same name (= two definition for the same class) one in AirShip Library and One in ASIHHTPRequest.

You can remove your ASIHTTPRequest and use the one shipped with AirShip library.

Comment: Hello, you are right i'm trying to use AirShip But as I reed their documentation I downloaded the source and the ASIHTTPRequest embedded on it. I didn't add any things. So is their any Solution ?

Comment: I don't know how to "Clean All Target" ?? tell me plz

Comment: In XCode Menu: Build > Clean All Targets

Comment: same error Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1